# QNetworkAccessManager used by QTimer causes falling

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QNetworkAccessManager in function, which is run periodically by QTimer. The code is:

```
QTimer* timer=new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(findUpdate()));
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    timer->start(frequency*1800000);

void MainWindow::findUpdate()
{
    for (int i=0;i<aplikace.count();i++){
        QNetworkAccessManager* manager=new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
        connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(checkUpdate(QNetworkReply*)));
        manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.gibucsoft.8u.cz/"+lang+"gibuclauncher/verze.php?ver="+aplikace.at(i))));
   }
}
```

The compilation is fine and when I run my application from the Qt Creator it is OK as well but when I run it from the OS the program falls after a while (but not long enough for the timer to even start the function findUpdate). Sometimes before falling this error message shows:
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Why are you allocating the QTimer and QNetworkAccessManager on the heap? This sounds like a questionable design.

Comment: You are saying program crashes before findUpdate() method but only sharing findUpdate() method. Can you give more of your code. And how sure are you about program never reaching findUpdate() method?

Comment: And there is no need to use multiple QNetworkAccessManager to fire severa get or postl requests at all. Just create one network access manager in constructor and use it. Also absolutely unclear how the get response handled. The author need to try this search "qt qnetworkaccessmanager example".

Comment: @AlexanderVX Yes the error was in multiple QNetworkAccessManager. When I use only one, the application seems to work fine. But strange is, that in previous versions of my application it worked with multiple instances as well. Thank for help.

Comment: @AlexanderVX It gets better: get the **compiler** to create a network access manager for you. That's done by holding it by value in `MainWindow`: `class MainWindow : public QWidget { QNetworkAccessManager m_nam(this); ... };`. The compiler then generates the code to create and destroy the instance of the manager for you. You don't even need to declare a constructor nor a destructor in the class!

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, pretty much like in most of apps or they share one instance of QNetworkAcessManager across the app. As long as we can always handle every individual QNetworkReply::finished signal there is no problem with that. I guess Martin Schmied may take a note of your comment,

Comment: @KubaOber Ok, thank for advice, how to code it better.